# Codeigniter: DB column select fallback

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

Im working on a codeigniter multi-language application and Im about to store languages in db like this:

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
   id   +   EN    +   HU
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
   hy   +   Hy!   +   Szia!
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    1   +   One   +   Egy
```

It can happen that a value is empty in "HU" column but its filled in "EN" because that's the default language. So the question is how can I select "HU" column with "EN" value fallback if its empty.

I know it can be easily solved with selecting both column and run a simple PHP script but my plan is to solve this problem with only MySQL.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try like that;

```
SELECT ( CASE WHEN HU IS NULL OR HU = '' THEN EN ELSE HU END ) AS LANG
FROM table_name
WHERE id = '1'
```

result when hu is empty id = '1'

```
One
```

result when hu is not empty id = '1'

```
Egy
```

NOTE : this query works correct only if you are trying to get lang HU!

`CASE WHEN` condition is kind of `IF statement` of SQL